# flutter http get - why do I get "Invalid request method" when accessing a server running on NodeMCU?

Tags: http, dart, flutter

When I try to make a request from a Flutter app to a server running on NodeMCU (microcontroller with Lua), I get the following error:

```
E/flutter (11080): [ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (11080): Invalid request method
E/flutter (11080): #0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:64:7)
E/flutter (11080): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11080): #1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:171:38)
E/flutter (11080): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11080): #2      BaseClient.get (package:http/src/base_client.dart:34:5)
E/flutter (11080): #3      get.<anonymous closure> (package:http/http.dart:47:34)
E/flutter (11080): #4      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:167:20)
E/flutter (11080): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11080): #5      get (package:http/http.dart:47:3)
E/flutter (11080): #6      _MyHomePageState._sendGet1 (file:///D:/dev/repos/github/thing_client/lib/main.dart:62:33)
E/flutter (11080): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11080): #7      _MyHomePageState.build.<anonymous closure> (file:///D:/dev/repos/github/thing_client/lib/main.dart:137:17)
E/flutter (11080): #8      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:494:14)
E/flutter (11080): #9      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:549:30)
E/flutter (11080): #10     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:102:24)
E/flutter (11080): #11     TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:161:9)
E/flutter (11080): #12     TapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:94:7)
E/flutter (11080): #13     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:315:9)
E/flutter (11080): #14     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:73:12)
E/flutter (11080): #15     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:101:11)
E/flutter (11080): #16     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:143:19)
E/flutter (11080): #17     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:121:22)
E/flutter (11080): #18     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:101:7)
E/flutter (11080): #19     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:64:7)
E/flutter (11080): #20     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:48:7)
E/flutter (11080): #21     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:134:13)
E/flutter (11080): #22     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:91:5)
```

The line this happens on is:

```
final response = await http.get('http://192.168.1.94', headers: {"Accept": "*/*"},);
```

The 'Accept' header makes no difference.
If instead I direct it to any other URL (e.g. "https://httpbin.org/get"), the request is performed correctly:

```
I/flutter (15857): {
I/flutter (15857):   "args": {}, 
I/flutter (15857):   "headers": {
I/flutter (15857):     "Accept": "*/*", 
I/flutter (15857):     "Accept-Encoding": "gzip", 
I/flutter (15857):     "Connection": "close", 
I/flutter (15857):     "Host": "httpbin.org", 
I/flutter (15857):     "User-Agent": "Dart/2.0 (dart:io)"
I/flutter (15857):   }, 
I/flutter (15857):   "origin": "89.69.232.252", 
I/flutter (15857):   "url": "https://httpbin.org/get"
I/flutter (15857): }
```

Trying the same request in CURL works for both:

```
$ curl -X GET "https://httpbin.org/get" -H  "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -H  "User-Agent: Dart/2.0 (dart:io)" -H  "Connection: close"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   254  100   254    0     0     96      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--    96{
  "args": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "Dart/2.0 (dart:io)"
  },
  "origin": "89.69.232.252",
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get"
}

$ curl -X GET "http://192.168.1.94" -H  "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -H  "User-Agent: Dart/2.0 (dart:io)" -H  "Connection: close"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    11    0    11    0     0     47      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    47{"empty":1}
```

The lua code for running the server is:

```
function serve(conn, payload)
    conn:send("{\"empty\":1}")
    conn:close()
end

srv=net.createServer(net.TCP)
srv:listen(80, function(conn)
    conn:on("receive",function(conn,payload)
        serve(conn, payload)
        collectgarbage()
    end) 
end)
```

The server has always worked well for me (in curl, wget, and browsers) and the get request in Flutter works fine for other servers. It's only the combination of the two that has a problem.
The [http package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http) version is 0.11.3+17

**[EDIT]** more info:
testing was done on a Huawei P9 Lite phone with Android 4.1.18.
Flutter build environment (w/ Android Studio) fully updated.
CURL testing done from laptop, tested also in browser both on laptop and on phone.
All devices (laptop, phone, server board) are direct clients of the same router, with static IPs.

Comment: are you testing on simulator ? real device ? android/ios? are you considering the local network ip?

Comment: @diegoveloper info added. I don't believe most of it matters, though, It works with other clients (e.g. browser on same phone)

Comment: Do you see the same issue if you test with a plain old Dart program? (Download the Dart SDK separately; don't use the one provided with flutter.) Try this 5 line programme: ```import 'package:http/http.dart';

main() async {
  Response r = await get('http://192.168.1.94', headers: {"Accept": "*/*"});
  print(r.statusCode);
}```

Comment: Does it make any difference with a closing `/` e.g. `http://192.168.1.94/`?

Comment: You probably need to send correct http headers back, otherwise Dart will not recognize the response as proper http. `conn:send("HTTP/1.0 200/OK\r\nServer: tiny lua webserver\r\n")`

Comment: Adding conn:send("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nServer: NodeMCU\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n") helped, dart's http no longer complains. I had made the response as minimal as I could, nothing before now had had a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit goes to @augustzf (see comment under question):

Flutter panics when it doesn't get a proper HTTP response, so the lua code needs to send e.g.:

```
conn:send("HTTP/1.0 200/OK\r\nServer: tiny lua webserver\r\n")
```